# Set a Static Member of a dynamically 'found' class

Tags: php, class, inheritance, properties, static

Trying to set an array and a count, which are both static members, by referencing them after getting the type of the current class. The intention is to have a global list of all items of a particular type that I have loaded, but I would like them to be split up into the static properties for each particular class. The issue is that I will be inheriting a few classes from a base class, but I want the static property in the 'child' class to get appended to.

Here's what I'm shooting for, give or take:

```
$Class = get_class($this);
($Class)::$List[($Class)::$Count++] = $this;
```

Comment: Note that SO is a Q&A site, not a forum. Answers should be posted separately from questions. Also, your code doesn't add anything to what VolkerK's does. You don't need a static `$Count` variable, as assigning to [empty brackets](http://php.net/array) (`$List[] = $this`) appends to an array. Also, you don't need to override constructors just to call the parent constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP 5.3 and later, you can use [late static binding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) to access overridden static variables. The short version is that you use `static` rather than `self` or the class name when accessing static variables. For example:

```
<?php
abstract class A {
    public function __construct() {
        static::$List[] = $this;
    }
}

class B extends A { 
    public static $List = array();
}

class C extends A {
    public static $List = array();  
}
$b = new B();
$c1 = new C();
$c2 = new C();
$c3 = new C();

echo '#objects of class C: ', count(C::$List), "\n";
var_dump(C::$List);
```

Keep in mind that if a child class defines a constructor, it must explicitly call the parent's constructor.

Comment: Already considered and accounted for; if this works, much thanks.

Comment: Beautiful. Much appreciated Sir.

Comment: I'd keep the $Count variable out and use $List[] and count($List), but that's probably a matter of choice...

Comment: Otherwise seems like class B will get an independent list from class... C, assuming C is identical to B?

Comment: Is it true that 'using my edited code, if I create a class C that is identical to class B, they will have independent lists'?

Comment: sorry, I still don't understand "a class C that is identical to class B". Do you mean `class C extends B { /* nothing in here */ }` ? But yes, two distinct classes will have/use two distinct lists.

Comment: I mean 'class C extends A{ }'; but I answered my own question; if class A has a List, and classes B and C both use parent::__construct to add to static::$List, all of the elements will be placed in the 'classAstatic::$List'. If however, I add a $List property to the subclasses, I.E. 'class D extends A{ public $List = null; }'; then elements of type D will be separated from elements of type A B and C.

Comment: @DigitalJedi805 you may find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3187124/peculiar-behaviour-with-php-5-3-static-inheritance-and-references useful for explaining how static class members work with regards to inheritance.